# What is the Ruby equivalent of the Perl `read()` function?

Tags: ruby, stdin

In Ruby, I want to read a certain length of character data from STDIN. In Perl, I'd be doing something like this:

```
# perl code
read(STDIN, $first_ten_chars, 10);
```

How would I do the same in Ruby?

Comment: @NiklasB. - Ya, a little more Googling has led me to the conclusion that that's the ticket. Wanna post that as an answer, or shall I just close my question?

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen you were almost right, just not quite OO enough ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [pre-defined STDIN variable](http://ruby.activeventure.com/manual/man-1.4/variable.html#CSTDIN) is an [IO object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html), so it has a [`read` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-read) which accepts as arguments a length and 'buffer', similar to the Perl `read` function:

```
first_ten_chars = STDIN.read(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

With ruby 1.9:

```
first_ten_chars = STDIN.gets(10)
```

Comment: But `gets` will read the next "line", so won't it stop at some delimiter? I want to read the next 10 characters, irrelevant of delimiters.

Comment: It will indeed, unless you do not use the default delimiter: `STDIN.gets(nil, 10)`

Comment: Ya, but at that point I think you might as well use `STDIN.read(10)`. Is there any other difference?